# How to initialise and access an array of collection objects

Tags: java, arrays, collections, set

I want to create an array of sets and access them for my program. But, since arrays cannot be merged with generic types, I have wrapped my `HashSet` class inside another class as given below.

```
Class MyClass{
    private HashSet<Integer> myKeys;
    public boolean add(Integer i) { return myKeys.add(i); }
    public boolean contains(Integer i){ return myKeys.contains(i); }
    public boolean remove(Integer i){ return myKeys.remove(i); }     
}
```

Later in my `main()` method, I had put the below code:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    MySets[] keys= new MySets[2];

    keys[1].add(1);
    keys[2].add(2);
    keys[1].add(2);
    keys[2].add(4);
    System.out.println("Key 1=" +keys[1]+" Key 2=" +keys[2]);                
}
```

I am unable to access any of the objects may be since they are not initialised as HashSets. Please suggest a possible solution to access the sets.

Comment: The class name doesn't correspond to the instances you want to create `MyClass` and `MySets`.  The `myKeys` variable should be initialzed like this `private HashSet<Integer> myKeys = new HashSet<Integer>();`

Comment: Please let me know if my answer solved your problem and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The objects on the array are null since you didn't initialize them.
You have to initialize them first.
You also have to initialize your `HashSet`.
You should work with the `Set` interface instead `HashSet`.

There's also a problem with the indexes of your array. Java indexes start from 0.

```
class MySets {
    private Set<Integer> myKeys = new HashSet<Integer>();
    public boolean add(Integer i) { return myKeys.add(i); }
    public boolean contains(Integer i){ return myKeys.contains(i); }
    public boolean remove(Integer i){ return myKeys.remove(i); }     
}

public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    MySets[] keys= new MySets[2];

    keys[0] = new MySets();
    keys[1] = new MySets();

    keys[0].add(1);
    keys[1].add(2);
    keys[0].add(2);
    keys[1].add(4);
    System.out.println("Key 1=" +keys[0]+" Key 2=" +keys[1]);                
}
```